# How are a left and right bit shift by 31 equal to & 0x7FFF

Tags: c, assembly

I am converting x86 Assembly to C code and cannot figure out why these two lines below equal the C code.

Assembly code:

```
sall $31, %eax
sarl $31, %eax
```

Equivalent C code:

```
int t = t & 0x7FFF;
```

Secondly, would an equivalent expression for the C code be:

```
t = t << 31;
t = t >> 31;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're *not* equivalent...

Comment: if you were doing a rotate depending on the instruction set it COULD look something like that but there would need to be more instructions involved to make that reduction.

Comment: Don't rely on the "equivalent C-expression", shifting like that is **undefined behaviour**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sall/sarl combo is not equivalent to AND 0x7FFF. Since it's an arithmetic shift (as opposed to logical), when shifting right, it fills the bits with the copy of the sign bit. So as a result, if eax had zero in the leftmost bit, it becomes zero, if it had one, it becomes 0xffffffff.

The SALL line shifts the register almost all the way to the left. The rightmost (0th) bit becomes the leftmost (31st, AKA the sign bit). Then shift right moves the leftmost bit back to the rightmost position, filling the shifted-in bits with its copy.

The `<<`/`>>` right combo **is** equivalent, as long as t is declared as a signed datatype (`int` is signed by default). Shifting unsigned datatypes doesn't sign-extend; on the assembly level, that's the SHRL command.

Comment: `sarl` is an *arithmetic* right-shift, thus replicates the sign bit.  So this is not equivalent to `& 1`.

Comment: Shifting into- and out of the sign bit of a signed integer type is undefined behaviour in C. The '`<<`/`>>`' combo is **not** equivalent, it's undefined for 32-bit int.

Comment: Name one x86 implementation where it doesn't work as expected. :) And if this behavior doesn't hold, C has no arithmetic shift at all, and the whole question has no answer.